# Write a method that returns the largest object in an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, methods, interface

Write a method that returns the largest object in an array of objects. The method signature is:

```
public static Object max(java.lang.Comparable[] a)
```

All the objects are instances of the `java.lang.Comparable` interface. The order of the objects in the array is determined using the `compareTo` method.

Write a test program in the main method that creates an array of ten Strings, an array of ten Integers, and an array of ten `java.util.Dates`, and finds the largest `String` (i.e. in the alphabetical order), `Integer`, and `Date` in the arrays.

Name your java class Max and your java file Max.java.

I am having a hard time grasping what exactly I need to do in this assignment. The two things I am really struggling with is how to use an interface and the `compareTo` method. To my understanding interfaces only hold methods then I would have to call the `compareTo` method outside of the interface? Anyway this is what I have so far.

```
public class Max {
    public static Object max(java.lang.Comparable[] a) {

        Object tempObj = new Object();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if ((a[i]).compareTo(a[i + 1]) > 0)
                tempObj = a[i];
            else
                tempObj = a[i + 1];
        }

        return tempObj;
    }

    // compare toMethod
    public void CompareTo() {
        a[i].compareTo(a[i + 1]);
    }
}// End Main

class MaxTest implements Max {
    public void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        String[] stringArray = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i",
            "j" };
        java.util.Date[] dateArray = {};

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            dateArray[j] = new java.util.Date();

    }// End Main
}//End Class
```

Comment: Think about the problem first.  In a list whose contents you've never seen before, the absolute largest element you've observed is negative infinity.  You want to build up from that.

Comment: This will harm you: `tempObj = new Object();`, as you're creating an object that does not implement `compareTo` and so that can't be compared; don't use it. Instead set tempObj to the first item in the array to start with. Don't give your Max class a `compareTo` method. It is not necessary and distracting.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there but

1. the `public void CompareTo` method is useless. BTW, you never use it.
2. The algorithm is incorrect. Think of what it would return for [4, 3, 2, 1], by executing it on paper. Also, think about what `a[i + 1]` is if i is equal to `a.length - 1`. What are the valid indices of an array?
3. I think you can safely assume your array will always have at least one element. If it's an array of integers, and it contains 42, what is the max element? Is it 42, or is it `new Object()`?
4. Your main method creates 3 arrays, but never calls the `max()` with any of these arrays method to see if it works fine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Indeed. Answer amended.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am going to re-work what I have with your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
public static Object max(Comparable[] a) {
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(a));
}
```

Comment: I doubt that's the goal of the assignment.